# Find all child forms in c# compact framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework

How do I find all the child dialogs for a form using c# and the compact framework.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this property?

[Form.MdiChildren](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdichildren.aspx)

Comment: Ups!... I didn´t know. Sorry :)